# Image doesn’t display in device for ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I using ionic 3

images file is \src\assets\img

basic page

```
export class BasicPage { 

items = [];

constructor(public nav: NavController ,private admob: AdMob) {
this.items = [

  {
    'title': ' Managing Coins & Gems ',
    'icon': 'assets/img/icone2.png',
    'description': ' a way to farm gems ifem pack.<br><br>  <img src="assets/img/pic3.jpg"> <br><br> Shadow Fight ments are about 15 seconds long for 1 Gem. <br><br>  <img src="./assets/img/pic4.jpg"> <br><br> There’s also a rewards by completing in game achievements. This usually gives a player about 1 Gem per achievement, but as you go through the game, the rewards ramp up proportionally. You havecon).<br><br>  <img src="assets/img/pic5.jpg"> <br><br>',
    'color': '#FFD439'
  },
  {
    'title': ' Gear Sets, Skill Trees & Moves ',
    'icon': 'assets/img/icone3.png',
    'description': ' Unless <br> Skill trees in the  bump. <br><br> <img src="assets/img/pic7.jpg"> <br><br>Make   ',
    'color': '#CE6296'
  },

]
}
```

and class navigation

```
export class NavigationDetailsPage {


item;
 constructor(params: NavParams) {
this.item = params.data.item;


}

}
```

in the html page nagivation

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Shadow Fight 2 guide</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openNavDetailsPage(item)" icon-start>
   <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src= {{item.icon}}>
      </ion-avatar>
      {{ item.title }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

navigation détailles

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      {{ item.title }}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-icon [name]="'logo-' + item.icon" [ngStyle]="{'color': item.color}"></ion-icon>
 <div [innerHTML]="item.description">
</div>

 
 
</ion-content>
```

ionic serve all is working nice
but 
ionic run --device
icon display but outher in the description not

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `ionic run --device` a new folder `www` is created with `assets` and `build` folder and all your `.ts` files are compiled to javascript and stored there in a single file named `main.js`. You should add `./`(dot) to tell the webview that images are in adjacent folder :

```
'icon': './assets/img/icone2.png',
```

Comment: yes i try ./assets ;././assets; ../assets no 1 of this workig

Comment: if u debug ur app by visiting `chrome://devices/` you can see the 404 error it throws, can u pls paste the error here ?

Comment: sorry ther is no error  I build apk  than install it but images not display

Comment: Heck, I have been searching high and low for an answer on this. It turns out you need 1 full stop in the image location for an image to appear, both on the app, and the emulator. Thanks so much! Seriously.

Comment: "full stop" - another term for ".", learned two new things today!

Answer (score 0):

Your image URL comes from a component, now you can use property binding, sometimes it does not work on the real device when we use img src like-

```
    <img src="{{item.icon}}">
```

then it works in the browser but in the real device sometimes it does not work, so here is another way we use property binding-

```
    <img [src]="item.icon">
```

it is work on the real device.